# How to get Custom Objects from JSON in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

Let us say I have an `NSObject` Class Person.

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *id;
@property NSString *name;
@property Address *billingAddress;
@end


@interface Address : NSObject

@property NSString *lane;
@property NSString *country;
@property NSString *zip;
@end
```

Now when I fetch the response from a URL, the response is in the form:

```
 {
  "response":
  {
  "Persons":[{"id":"2232","name":"John","Address":{"lane":"Adelaide Avenue","country":"Canada","zip":"45503"}}{"id":"3422","name":"Jane","Address":{"lane":"Victoria Avenue","country":"Australia","zip":"34903"}}]
  }
}
```

I want to parse the response directly into objects without having to write a method to read and assign objects from `NSDictionary`. Is there are no objects to parse directly from the response to Object based on the Object parameters similar to "GSon" in Android.

EDIT:

I have used the below code to have generic class that does the job for strings without having to know  about the object itself.

```
for (NSString *key in [dct allKeys]) { 
    if ([cat respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) { 
           [cat setValue:[dct valueForKey:key] forKey:key]; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: You can use open sources like RESTKit to map JSON responses directly to the custom object or even entity.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for something like that. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I did get a JSON framework that does exactly what I wanted - [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel).

We just need to specify Models and relationships and all the logic for converting JSON response to the models is handled by the framework. Very handy.

Basic usage :
Consider you have a `JSON` response like

`{"id":"10", "country":"Germany", "dialCode": 49, "isInEurope":true}`

The corresponding model will be

```
#import "JSONModel.h" 

@interface CountryModel : JSONMode 
@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* country;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* dialCode;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isInEurope;

@end
```

We don't need to write additional code in the .m file to parse and assign values to the variables. Now to initialise the model from the response we just need to do the below

```
NSString* json = (fetch JSON here)
NSError* err = nil;
CountryModel* country = [[CountryModel alloc] initWithString:json error:&err];
```

The works well with complex data structures as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such magic, not even in Android's GSon!!!

Some where down the line you need to write code for converting JSON to your object.

You may create a generic class, or a method (just once) to convert all dictionary values to your object.

Comment: So I could create a generic class that handles all of these assignments and write something like the below to handle assignments.

cat is the object I want assignments to happen for.

            for (NSString *key in [dct allKeys]) {
                if ([cat respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
                    [cat setValue:[dct valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
            }